# Rearranging elements in a row matlab

Tags: matlab, cell, element

I have two matrices in Matlab.

A = [image]

and

B = 
[image]

I want to assign the elements having the same cell-value according to it's corresponding column number in A matrix and move the elements there. I want to map the elements of B with A so that B elements also moves in that position.

I want this

A = [image]

And therefore,

B = [image]

Is there a way to do this?!
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way I can think of is to create row/column pairs where the rows correspond row locations of the matrix and column locations are the actual elements of the matrix themselves.  The values seen at these row/column pairs are again just the matrix values themselves.

You can very easily do this with [`sparse`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html).  Recreating the matrix above and storing this in `A`:

```
A = [1 2 5 8; 1 2 4 7];
```

... I would do it this way:

```
r = repmat((1:size(A,1)).', 1, size(A,2)); %'
S = full(sparse(r(:),A(:),A(:)));
```

The first line of code generates row locations for each value in the matrix `A`, then using `sparse` to specify row/column pairs and the associated values and we use [`full`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/full.html) to convert to a proper numeric matrix.

We get:

```
S =

     1     2     0     0     5     0     0     8
     1     2     0     4     0     0     7     0
```

You can also do the same for the matrix `B`.  You'd use `sparse` and specify the third parameter to be `B` instead:

```
B = [0.5 0.2 0.6 0.8; 0.4 0.6 0.8 0.9];
S2 = full(sparse(r(:),A(:),B(:)));
```

We get:

```
>> S2

S2 =

    0.5000    0.2000         0         0    0.6000         0         0    0.8000
    0.4000    0.6000         0    0.8000         0         0    0.9000         0
```

Comment: thanks. The description of the problem changed. Sorry for that.

Comment: @user5916581 That's usually frowned upon. You should thoroughly check your question before posting. I've changed my answer anyway.

Comment: @user5916581 That's alright. It was a very easy change to incorporate your new changes.

Comment: rayryeng@ I was just wondering if there is '0' in the A matrix to start with. How to deal with it? "Error using sparse Index into matrix must be positive."

Comment: You can't have zeroes. You said this matrix indexes the columns of the result and MATLAB starts indexing at 1.

Comment: adding 1 and ignoring 1st column did good. Thanks. It's solved.